# ngSrc with angular and blade on Laravel 5.4

Tags: angularjs, laravel-5.4, laravel-blade

I need to show a picture in a blade view loaded dynamically with AngularJS.

this is the short piece of code causing me many headaches since many days:

`<img ng-src="@{{ $video.thumb }}" width="57">`

if I put `@{{ $video.thumb }}` outside the img ng-src I get the correct path of the image.
I wouldn't change the whole app using interpolate provider.

```
 var sampleApp = angular.module('sampleApp', [], function($interpolateProvider) {
        $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<%');
        $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('%>');
    });
```

More in HTML if I search with the inspector for the img tag I can't see anything, just

`<img width="57">`

I'm running it locally.

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

I post the solution if someone else need it.

I had to use the full url in the `ng-src`.
Since I'm using Laravel and I'm working on a Blade view I had to use the following code:

`<img ng-src="{{ url('/') }}/storage/@{{ video.thumb }}" width="57">`

with `{{ url('/') }}` to get the domain url, then added `/storage/` because I saved my files in that folder and at the end the angular var.